# bundle exec rake db:migrate >> ROUTING ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, bundle, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dbmigrate

I got a small problem. I'm new and reading through the guides on how to build a **demo_app**. 
I started with **'$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string'**  
After successfully generating the scaffold command; 
I use **'$bundle exec rake db:migrate'**
I start rails server, and go to **localhost:3000**; 
I try going to **localhost:3000/users** and it says *[ROUTING ERROR -- No route matches [GET] "/users"]* 


 
what did i do wrong? 
I've followed all the steps from the guides and it's suppose to show "the list of users"

Any Help is much appreciated..

Regards, 
Marc

Comment: That's strange. Given your steps, it sounds like you did the right things. Did the rake db:migrate run successfully? You should see some output that it called create_table(:users) and that it didn't throw an exception.

Comment: Can you paste here config/routes.rb?

Comment: it was already at resources :users ... not sure why it didnt work the first time. i restarted my cpu and it works perfectly. thanks for the help guys. i appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server was running before you generated the scaffold, then you should try to restart the server. Other than that please ensure the following line appears in your *config/routes.rb*

`resources :users`

I hope it helps.